# Replace elements with values from another xml file

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have the following xml files:

1) source.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <Name><SSTVal>Name</SSTVal></Name>
  <Version><SSTVal>Version</SSTVal></Version>
  <Messages>
      <Message><SSTVal>Message</SSTVal></Message>
  </Messages>
</root>
```

2) values.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Values>
  <SSTVal name="Name">Test Name</SSTVal>
  <SSTVal name="Version">1.2.3</SSTVal>
  <SSTVal name="Message">Hello World!</SSTVal>
</Values>
```

I'm trying to write an xslt file, which searches every occurrence of SSTVal in the first file and replaces it with the value of matching SSTVal from the second file,  so the result would look like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <Name>Test Name</Name>
  <Version>1.2.3</Version>
  <Messages>
      <Message>Hello World!</Message>
  </Messages>
</root>
```

I managed so far to write the following xslt transormation, which replaces only one particular node but with all the values from the values.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <!--xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/-->
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:variable name="vReps" select="document('file:///c:/test/values.xml')"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- replace element text -->
  <xsl:template match="SSTVal[text()='Version']">
    <xsl:value-of select="$vReps"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Could you help me to change the xslt in order to replace matching elements.
Thank you in advance!

EDIT: XSLT 1.0 shall be used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `<xsl:variable name="vReps" select="document('file:///c:/test/values.xml')"/>` to `<xsl:variable name="vReps" select="document('file:///c:/test/values.xml')//SSTVal"/>` and then it would be nice to be able to change

```
  <xsl:template match="SSTVal[text()='Version']">
    <xsl:value-of select="$vReps"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

to

```
  <xsl:template match="SSTVal[. = $vReps/@name]">
    <xsl:value-of select="$vReps[current() = @name]"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

only using a variable reference in a pattern is not allowed in XSLT 1.0, so we need to have a check inside the template:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:variable name="vReps" select="document('values.xml')//SSTVal"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()"  name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="SSTVal">

        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$vReps[current() = @name]">
                <xsl:value-of select="$vReps[current() = @name]"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <!-- not sure you want to raise an error with xsl:message or leave the element -->
                <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In XSLT 2.0 we could simplify the code to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:param name="value-uri" select="'values.xml'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="value-doc" select="document($value-uri)"/>

    <xsl:key name="val" match="SSTVal" use="@name"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="SSTVal[key('val', ., $value-doc)]">
        <xsl:value-of select="key('val', ., $value-doc)"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you! I assume it's XSLT 2.0, isn't it?

Comment: No, in XSLT 2.0 I would suggest to define a key and use that, the posted code is XSLT 1.0. Or I suppose it is, looking at it now I am not sure I can use the variable in the match pattern, so I will have to test.

Comment: You are awesome, Martin!  I messed xml during testing, that's why it didn't work. That works fine now, even with  <xsl:template match="SSTVal">, any idea, what could be a problem removing [. = $vReps/@name]?

Comment: @oachkatzlschwoaf, see the edit for a tested XSLT 1.0 attempt, I am afraid the use of the variable reference is indeed not allowed in the pattern, so you need to have a check inside the pattern or don't check, if you are sure all elements have a replacement match in the other file.